# Putting HTML inside dynamically made column on aspx GridView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i'm trying to put a html div that contains an style that represents a dot (green, yellow or red). The thing is: I have to put this html inside a gridview (histRagStatus) column that was programatically made, as you can see:

```
    private void popularHistoricoRAGStatus()
    {
             DataTable ragTable =ProjetoBO.HistoricoRAGStatusProjeto(Convert.ToInt32(Session["idProjeto"]));

        int agrupadorRagStatus = -1;

        int cont = 1;

        var tabelaFinal = PegarDataTable();

        DataRow dataRow = tabelaFinal.NewRow();

        foreach (DataRow row in ragTable.Rows)
        {
            cont++;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row[9]) != agrupadorRagStatus)
            {
                cont = 1;
                agrupadorRagStatus = Convert.ToInt32(row[9]);
                tabelaFinal.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                dataRow = tabelaFinal.NewRow();
                dataRow[1] = PegarCorIndicadorRagStatus(Convert.ToInt32(row[3]),row[6].ToString());
                continue;
            }
            dataRow[0] = DateTime.Parse(row[2].ToString()).ToShortDateString();

            dataRow[cont] = PegarCorIndicadorRagStatus(Convert.ToInt32(row[3]), row[6].ToString());

        }

        histRagStatus.DataSource = tabelaFinal;
        histRagStatus.DataBind();
   }
```

I got this DataTable that I fill with data from the database and I put it as a data source to the grid view. But Here is the problem: when I have a table with static column, that I put while on design, it works OK, the html is converted into the images, but when I put the SAME HTML into a programatically made column, it doesn't work, it becomes the HTML text itself as you can see here https://www.dropbox.com/s/rf07ecu66axmzg0/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo.png

I'm stuck with this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: try setting HtmlEncode = false within the definition of the GridView

Comment: I tried it already, no luck =(

Comment: Sorry, it should be in the column definition, not the grid itself

Comment: ok, when I put it on the boudfield on the column tag doesn't work, does it have to be with the dynamicfield tag to work?

Comment: can you show your markup for the grid? technically it is a dynamic column, so that's what it should be, you can still bind to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your new column assign HtmlEncode="False"

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:DynamicField HtmlEncode="False"></asp:DynamicField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I've put it, but with dynamicfield it threw an exception, so I put BoundField, and it didn't work also, how do I put the dynamicfield tag on the gridview that is fed data like that?

Comment: it's the same as the one you made it here, it's identical.

Comment: sorry                                                                                                                                    <asp:GridView ID="histRagStatus" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:DynamicField HtmlEncode="False"></asp:DynamicField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

Comment: it gives the error 'Could not determine a MetaTable. A MetaTable could not be determined for the data source '' and one could not be inferred from the request URL.' when I bind a DataTable to this gridview